# UIView components loaded but not displayed

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, segue

I have a ViewController that does not display all of its components.
I use a performSegue to achieve this VC.
These components are a UILabel and one to two UIButton, it depends on the times.

When I use Debug View Hierarchy, I see that the components are loaded, so, for example, if I make a rotation of the screen, some appear, the UIButton not displayed, respond correctly to the "Touch" if I touch on the place where it is supposed to be the element (and make it appear by the same way)

I also have no problems if I put this VC in "Root View Controller", only from a Segue.

Do you have any ideas on the cause of the problem?

**Edit I**

I forgot to say that moving the application in the background and returning to it also makes it possible to make appear the components.

Below the viewDidLoad & viewDidAppear functions

```
class CameraView: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var titleUI: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var cancelUI: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var flipUI: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var captureUI: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var previewUI: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var flashUI: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var touchUI: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var retryUI: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var validateUI: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var resultUI: UIImageView!

    var callBack: (Int, UIImage?) -> Void = {
        (status: Int, image: UIImage?) -> Void in
    }
    private var cameraHandler = CameraManager()
    private var flash: CameraFlashMode = .off

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        cancelUI.setIcon(icon: .googleMaterialDesign(.reply), iconSize: 45, color: .white, forState: .normal)
        flipUI.setIcon(icon: .googleMaterialDesign(.switchCamera), iconSize: 45, color: .white, forState: .normal)
        captureUI.setIcon(icon: .googleMaterialDesign(.cameraAlt), iconSize: 45, color: .white, forState: .normal)
        flashUI.setIcon(icon: .googleMaterialDesign(.flashOff), iconSize: 45, color: .white, forState: .normal)
        retryUI.setIcon(prefixText: "", prefixTextColor: .white, icon: .googleMaterialDesign(.chevronLeft), iconColor: .white, postfixText: "Retry", postfixTextColor: .white, forState: .normal, textSize: 15, iconSize: 20)
        validateUI.setIcon(prefixText: "", prefixTextColor: .white, icon: .googleMaterialDesign(.done), iconColor: .white, postfixText: "Save", postfixTextColor: .white, forState: .normal, textSize: 15, iconSize: 20)

        resultUI.clipsToBounds = true
        resultUI.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

        cancelUI.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.cancel)))
        captureUI.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.capture)))
        flashUI.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.switchFlashMode)))
        flipUI.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.turnCamera)))
        validateUI.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.validate)))
        retryUI.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.retry)))

        cameraHandler.cameraDevice = .back
        cameraHandler.showAccessPermissionPopupAutomatically = false
        cameraHandler.flashMode = flash
        cameraHandler.animateCameraDeviceChange = true
        cameraHandler.cameraOutputMode = .stillImage
        cameraHandler.cameraOutputQuality = .high
        cameraHandler.writeFilesToPhoneLibrary = false
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        cameraHandler.askUserForCameraPermission{result in
            if !result {
                self.callBack(PERMISSION_REFUSED, nil)
                self.close(reason: PERMISSION_REFUSED)
            }
        }
        self.view.setNeedsDisplay()
        retry()
    }
...
}
```

**Edit II**

I was about to add screenshots to show the differences and I realized that on the screenshots, all the items are displayed, although this is obviously not the case on the device

Comment: Considering the fact that if you rotate the screen, you can see these UI elements, your Autolayout is probably not set up properly. What happens on devices with other screen size?

Comment: please add some screen shots or code.

Comment: Add your done work.

Comment: If i make this VC as "Root View Controller", all is correct. Also, the Debug View Hierarchy show me that the components are loaded and well placed. I try on multiple simulator and reals Ipad 2 and Ipad pro. Autolayout is set. I add the ViewDidLoad and ViewDidAppears on my post.

Comment: Well in normal state, you are unable to see them because you have set there color white , and when you touched them their states changed and they just appear for a while .. ??? Is that happening ??

Comment: Add screen shot of properties of storyboard ..

Comment: Are you using a library? where did you get the `setIcon` function?

Comment: @BrightFuture yes, but, all icons are build with the same way and some of them are correctly displayed, also, i have a UILabel build without any library. Something even stranger, look at the second edit of my post...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the library you used.

The way to add a button and a label to the screen is almost identical, you set the frame you add content (text, image), you add subview to their parents (whether in IB or by code), and if you don't change anything after that, you certainly have a button or a label on the screen.

As you mentioned the label is correctly set, that mean this isn't some weird bugs that cause the button to not show, it's simply the way you set it, which is using the `setIcon` function. I believe there are some steps you did wrong using this library, as I don't know the library, I can't tell you exactly what, but the problem is here.

There's an alternative to achieve the same thing you want without bugs, go to https://material.io/icons/ to download the images you want, and set the image of the buttons with the `UIKit` method `setImage`, you should get it right then.